# calculating daily average across 30 years for different variables

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe that has daily information (measured data) across 30 years for different variables. I am trying to groupby days of the year, and then find a mean across 30 years. How do I go about this? This is what the dataframe looks like

[image: og dataframe]

I tried to groupby day after checking for type of YYYYMMDD (it's an int64 type.) now I have the dataframe looking like this. It has just added new columns for Day, Month year

[[image: new columns]]

I'm a bit stuck on how to calculate means from here, i would need to somehow group all Jan-1sts, jan-2nds etc over 30 years and average it after.

Comment: give us the DataFrame as a reproducible code so we can test with it, and would you add what did you try as code

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` with `month` and `day`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
( df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean().reset_index().
                  rename({'level_0':'month', 'level_1':'day'}, axis=1))
```

or if you want to group them by the day of year, i.e. `1, 2, .. 365`, set `as_index=False`:

```
df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day], as_index=False).mean()
```